# Nonisomorphic connected 2-regular graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A $k$-regular graph on $n$ vertices is a graph in which the degree of every vertex is $k$. How to show that the number of non-isomorphic connected 2-regular graphs is $\frac {(n-1)!} {2}$

Comment: I know that you are cheating, and I have looked at your previous posts and see that you have cheated before as well. Take down this question or I will report this to the administration. Cheating on an exam where research is encouraged is the height of stupidity.

Comment: Then what is the appropriate protocol to have this removed?

Comment: There's a flagging system, but it's not accesible to someone of your reputation. Also, it's usually the quality of the question that has it removed, not the reasons why it's been written. The only ecception I've seen is for questions of ongoing online context. I know it's frowned upon, but I do not know how moderators deal with them.

Comment: To a great extent the horse already bolted, so the benefit of locking the stable now is iffy. Save a link to this question, and report it to the professor/admin. If there is an honor code violation that is first and foremost their problem. We have a continuously developing (but non-binding) policy about homework help, and regulars are keen to catch cheaters. But I'm afraid we don't have the resources to hunt down cheaters in exams.

Comment: Thransom, because the question has an upvoted answer, the site software now prevents the original asker from deleting it. Also, for legal reasons I am prohibited from disclosing personally identifying information about the poster. Therefore you should deal with dishonesty at your institution. This was discussed in our meta some time back. Searching.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/take-home-test-policy/3332#3332), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9021/posting-exam-questions/9031#9031), and related discussion [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11189/is-it-our-responsibility-to-police-for-competition-exam-etc-questions).

Comment: Thransom, many prominent users here are university level teachers, so we share your pain, and like to help as much we can. It is not impossible that internet means an end to take-home exams. Anyway, your post is not an answer to the question, so I will move it and these comments under the main post and lock it for a little while. My advice is that you do report this to the administration. If you need more help from the site, then you should ask the people at S (use the *contact us* link). They also no the legal stuff better than I do.

Comment: user117911: You cannot cover your tracks that easily. This is the internet. Nothing ever disappears from here. If you cheated, you have to man up and face the consequences.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be false. A connected $2$-regular graph on $n$ vertices is a cycle which is clearly unique.

If you are counting simply the number of non-isomorphic $2$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices then too the question seems false. For $n=4$ there is only $1$ such graph. The answer in this case would be the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of the number $n$ with least summand $3$. I am not aware of a closed form formula for this.

Two sequences on OEIS which are related to the question are [A005176](http://oeis.org/A005176) and [A005177](http://oeis.org/A005177).

---

Update: If the question is regarding counting labelled connected $2$-regular graphs then we can show that the answer is $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ as follows:

Label the vertices $1,2,\ldots,n$. The only realization of a connected $2$-regular graph is as an $n$-cycle and hence we need to count the possible cycles on these vertices. To see that exactly $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ cycles can be formed fix the vertex $1$ and consider all the $(n-1)!$ arrangements of the $n-1$ numbers $2,3,\ldots,n$ appended to $1$. These correspond to possible cycles. For example if $n=4$ we have $1234,1243,1324,1342,1423,1432$ as the possible cycles.

However each such arrangement is actually duplicated twice as the same cycle when the last $n-1$ terms are written in reverse order. For example the cycle $1234$ and the cycle $1432$ are the same. It is clear that there can be no other cycles. Hence there are precisely $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ such cycles. This proves the result.

Comment: On the other hand, if the OP wants the number of connected $2$-regular graphs on $n$ **labeled** vertices (a completely different question from the one he stated), then $\frac{(n-1)!}2$ is of course the correct answer (for $n\gt2$).